# 2 Electricity generator connected

Tags: energy-conservation, energy

I'd like to know (my knowledge at physics are realy poor) what would happen if I've got a generator connected to another generator and both of them generating electricity for a house or whatever.

Like this:

G1 is connected to G2 and the plug. So it gives electricity to both of them making G2 to "load electricity" and plug usable.

When G1's energy is finished, G2 starts using the "loaded electricity" making G1 to "load electricity" and still the plug usable.

Woudn't that make an infinite electricity system?

Thanks!

Diego

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume with energy you mean electricity, and your generators sound like rechargeable batteries to me. In that case you have a [series connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits#Cells_and_batteries), which will simply double the voltage available.

No, this wouldn't generate infinite energy. Whatever you do, each generator needs fuel that contains chemical energy. In the best (=impossible) case it would be entirely converted into electrical energy. Whether you temporarily store a part of G1's energy in G2 or not does not change anything about the fact that the total energy cannot exceed the chemical energy of your fuel (unless of course there are other influences, e.g. a solar panel and the very energetic sun which won't run out of fuel for some billion years...)